# Can't convert Thrift's cql result from Byte array to String using UTF-8 charset

Tags: java, utf-8, cassandra, thrift, cql3

I'm trying to convert cql query result to String and then to int but it fails on first step. I've got following method:

```
private int getNextId() {
    int nextId = -1;
    CqlResult cr = null;

    try {
        cr = client.execute_cql3_query(ByteBuffer.wrap("select * from counter".getBytes()), Compression.NONE,
                ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
        Column column = cr.getRows().get(0).getColumns().get(1);
        nextId = Integer.parseInt(new String(column.getValue(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // default try-catch for example purpose
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return nextId;
}
```

On debug, column's bytes value is `1B`. During conversion to String it ends up as few *squares* instead of `27`. Also on debug CqlResult variable contains following information: `default_value_type:UTF8Type`. As far as I know Cassandra also stores data using UTF-8. Why it doesn't work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you run `select * from counter` in cqlsh, what result do you see?

Comment: @Aaron     'id | counter ----+---------  0 |      27  (1 rows)'   - result of this query